# Accessing functions between Kivy classes: tips and resources needed

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.9

I'm calling another class with the same name instead of the existing class all the time and the code continues as if nothing happened, I don't know if this is something specific to kivy, how can I learn to call functions between kivy classes without any errors?  Is there any place that says this?  I've given the piece of code I'm currently stuck with as an example of where I went wrong on the bottom side.

```
class MainMenu(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(MainMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        

    def scOpener(self):

        self.ids.mmb.pos = (-200, 0)

class OpChooseScreen(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(OpChooseScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        

        self.mm = MainMenu()

        

    def up(self):

        self.mm.scOpener()

        

class FirstScreen(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        

class FirstApp(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.fs = FirstScreen()

        

    def build(self, **kwargs):

        Window.clearcolor = (0,0,0,1)

        return self.fs

        

if __name__ == "__main__":

    FirstApp().run()
```

I don't know how to access the up function in the opchoosescreen class, the scopener function in the mainmenu class, are there any resources that you can read (especially read this part) for such cases?  I tried to read python's original site but couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, i solve my own question.
I add App.get_running_app().root.ids.mm.scOpener()
instead of self.mm.scOpener()